Setting ThreadBasePriority by NtSetInformationThread returns STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT (0x80000002) when called from .Net 8
I want my .Net 8 application to use threads that run in Soft Real-Time (Windows 10 Iot 2021). According to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/soft-real-time/soft-real-time documentation, I need to use NtSetInformationThread to set ThreadBasePriority to a value between 16 and 31.
The problem is that I am not able to set ThreadBasePriority, the return code is always 0x80000002. This also happens when I want to set the priority not in real time, so I assumed that it is not a problem with thread permissions.
What I tested:
[DllImport("Ntdll.dll")]
public extern static uint NtSetInformationThread(IntPtr hThread, int ThreadInformationClass, IntPtr ThreadInformation, CULong ThreadInformationLength);

static void Test()
{
    var rt = NtSetInformationThread(GetCurrentThread(), 3, 31, new CULong(sizeof(int)));

    var hex = rt.ToString("X");
}


ThreadInformation shoud be a in or ref. What is the CULong type?

Thank you, it works with ref. CULong is due to the fact that I am using .NET 8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#cc-long

Your DllImport definition is not correct. The ThreadInformation parameter is supposed to be a pointer to the data you want to pass. For ThreadBasePriority that appears to be an int.
Note that you need to specify both [In] and in as these do different things.
[DllImport("Ntdll.dll")]
public extern static uint NtSetInformationThread(
  IntPtr hThread,
  int ThreadInformationClass,
  [In] in int ThreadInformation,
  CULong ThreadInformationLength);

